# Why doesn't this script overwrite the counter file?

Tags: bash, shell-script

When the script runs the command to restart the service, I want to restart the loop counter. For some reason it resets it only when I kill the script altogether and restart it.

```
### CONFIGURATION
# path to jcli
JCLI="jcli"
JCLI_PORT=3100

LAST_BLOCK=""

START_TIME=$SECONDS

# this sets the counter file and it does indeed write it back to 0 when the script is started and stopped. 

TEMPFILE=/tmp/counter.tmp
echo 0 > $TEMPFILE

# block log file
BLOCK_LOG=/home/coconut/logs/block.log

# how many seconds should we wait if no blocks show up
RESTART_GT=240

# display output headers
echo "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////"
echo "///////////////////////// JORMUNGANDR NODE MONITOR //////////////////////////////////"
echo "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////"
echo ""
echo "TODAY DATE | EP | SLOT# | EXP TIME | LOC TIME | HEIGHT | LAST HASH | COUNTER"
echo ""

echo "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////" >> ${BLOCK_LOG}
echo "///////////////////////// JORMUNGANDR NODE MONITOR //////////////////////////////////" >> ${BLOCK_LOG}
echo "/////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////" >> ${BLOCK_LOG}
echo ""  >> ${BLOCK_LOG}
echo "TODAY DATE | EP | SLOT# | EXP TIME | LOC TIME | HEIGHT | LAST HASH | COUNTER" >> ${BLOCK_LOG}
echo ""  >> ${BLOCK_LOG}


while true
do
    DATE=$(date '+%Y-%m-%d')
    TIME=$(date '+%H:%M:%S')
    LAST_HASH=$($JCLI rest v0 node stats get --host "http://127.0.0.1:${JCLI_PORT}/api" | grep lastBlockHash | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c 1-10)
    LATEST_BLOCK=$($JCLI rest v0 node stats get --host "http://127.0.0.1:${JCLI_PORT}/api" | grep lastBlockHeight | awk '{print $2}' | rev | cut -c 2- | rev | cut -c 2-)
    LATEST_SLOT=$($JCLI rest v0 node stats get --host "http://127.0.0.1:${JCLI_PORT}/api" | grep lastBlockDate | awk '{print $2}' | rev | cut -c 2- | rev | cut -c 5- )
    LAST_BLOCK_TIME=$($JCLI rest v0 node stats get --host "http://127.0.0.1:${JCLI_PORT}/api" | grep lastBlockTime | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c 13- | rev | cut -c 8- | rev)
    EPOCH=$($JCLI rest v0 node stats get --host "http://127.0.0.1:${JCLI_PORT}/api" | grep lastBlockDate | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c -3 | cut -c 2- )
    if [ "$LATEST_BLOCK" > 0 ]; then
        if [ "$LATEST_BLOCK" != "$LAST_BLOCK" ]; then
            COUNTER=$((COUNTER+1))
            START_TIME=$(($SECONDS))
            echo "${DATE} | ${EPOCH} | ${LATEST_SLOT} | ${LAST_BLOCK_TIME} | ${TIME} | 0${LATEST_BLOCK} | ${LAST_HASH} | ${COUNTER}"
            echo "${DATE} | ${EPOCH} | ${LATEST_SLOT} | ${LAST_BLOCK_TIME} | ${TIME} | 0${LATEST_BLOCK} | ${LAST_HASH} | ${COUNTER}" >>  ${BLOCK_LOG}
            LAST_BLOCK="$LATEST_BLOCK"
        else
            ELAPSED_TIME=$(($SECONDS - $START_TIME))
            if [ "$ELAPSED_TIME" -gt "$RESTART_GT" ]; then
                echo "//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////"
                echo "${DATE} | ${TIME} | Restarting Jormungandr. | Waited ${ELAPSED_TIME} for block."

                echo "//////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////" >>  ${BLOCK_LOG}
                echo "${DATE} | ${TIME} | Restarting Jormungandr. | Waited ${ELAPSED_TIME} for block." >>  ${BLOCK_LOG}

                sudo service jorg restart
                LAST_BLOCK="$LATEST_BLOCK"
                echo "Sleeping for 90 sec."
                sleep 90


                ## this is where it should reset the counter to 0 since the script is being restarted
                echo 0 >! ${TEMPFILE}


            fi
        fi
    else
        echo "No block height"
        # Reset time
        START_TIME=$(($SECONDS))
    fi
    sleep 20
done

exit 0
```

Answer (score 2):

The command

```bash
echo 0 >! ${TEMPFILE}
```

writes a `0` and the contents of the variable `TEMPFILE` to a file called `!`.  It is equivalent to

```bash
echo 0 ${TEMPFILE} > "!"
```

What I assume you meant to do is

```bash
echo 0 > "$TEMPFILE"
```

or possibly

```bash
echo 0 >| "$TEMPFILE"
```

This would truncate the file named by `$TEMPFILE` and write a `0` followed by a newline into the file.

I'm not entirely sure what you use this file for, as you only ever write zeros into it. But the above line was the line that you had commented upon in the script, and it does indeed have an issue with its redirection.

---

Other random comments:

- You do several calls to `$JCLI rest v0 node stats get --host "http://127.0.0.1:${JCLI_PORT}/api"`.  If this is something that takes any amount of time or uses any resources, it may be better to do it only once and save the result to a file that you later parse several times.
- The pipeline `grep lastBlockTime | awk '{print $2}' | cut -c 13- | rev | cut -c 8- | rev` looks overly complicated.  You can most likely do this with a single call to `sed` or `awk`, for example `awk '/lastBlockTime/ { print substr($2, 13, 8) }'` or something similar.
- You use a number of variables unquoted. Consider double quoting them to avoid issues if their values at some point may contain blanks or globbing pattern characters.
- The `exit 0` at the end masks any error at the end of the script, so you wouldn't be able to call the script and then detect whether it ran ok or not.
- The script lacks a `#!`-line specifying what interpreter to use for running the script.

Comment: ohhh ok i see i didn't have the quotes around it. thanks. i know some of that is kinda bulky, im new to learning bash scripting and awk and sed look super complicated :)

Comment: @jon The main issue is not actually the quoting there, but the `>!`, which redirects to a file called `!`.  Did you mean to use `>|`?